# How to find string length for the multi language sentence in IOS

Tags: objective-c, unicode, nsstring, multilingual, string-length

I am developing an application that needs to restrict user from entering string text unto 200 characters.

The user is allowed to enter string value in any language.

I am able to get the string length for the english characters but not for the other languages.

Can any one help me.

Expected Result:

- 'Roger is a nice guy' -19
- 'रॉजर एक छान माणूस आहे'  - 16
- '罗杰是一个好人' - 7

Comment: Is there are reason that `string.length` does not work?  Are you actually trying to count glyphs?

Comment: @Avi Characters are a different concept than glyphs. Consider ligatures, for example. `ﬃ` is a ligature that combines three characters into one glyph.

Comment: I am quite well aware of that.  I was trying to get the question poster to clarify that is what she wants.  I came up with basically the same code you did as an answer, but I didn't post it because you beat me to it.

Comment: @Avi Thinking about the difference between glyphs and characters made me try them on `NSString` (and Swift String). Both return the ligature as a single character. Hm.

Comment: Characters are a fuzzy concept when you talk about Unicode.  Ligatures can be a single character, or they can be a combination of characters.  That's why I specifically asked about glyphs, and not characters.  A glyph is the visual representation of one or more characters.  It's what most people mean when they say character.

Comment: Another point: When a glyph can be represented by a single character or a collection of characters, the composed character is the single character and the decomposed characters are the set of individual characters that are equivalent to the composed character.  Most (or all) accents and ligatures have composed and decomposed forms.

Comment: @Avi I agree that the concept is fuzzy. Yet I think "glyph" is not much better to define what you really mean. The OP for example wants the first example string to be 19 "characters", which means spaces are to be considered characters. Glyphs don't represent whitespace, so in this case it's not what the OP wants.

Comment: Why do you think there are no glyphs to represent whitespace?

Comment: It may be technically inaccurate to say there's a glyph for a space character, but if we define glyph to be the visual representation of one or more characters, the definition applies to space just as much as any visible character-thingy.  It's the visual representation of an invisible character, if you will :)

Comment: Take a look at https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html

Comment: All this confusion just underlines my point: Glyph is fuzzy or at least unknown, too. But our discussion probably serves your case: Pointing out the problems of a proper "character" definition :)

Comment: Sidenote: Just checked, and at least Core Text thinks "Helvetica" has a glyph named "space".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for `extended grapheme clusters`, which is a good definition of a user perceived character. Swift String's `character` view provides this conveniently.

Cocoa's `NSString` provides `enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:` which can be used to count "composed character sequences", which is similar:

```
@interface NSString (ComposedCharacterSequenceCount)
@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter=nr_composedCharacterSequenceCount) NSInteger composedCharacterSequenceCount;
@end

@implementation NSString (ComposedCharacterSequenceCount)
- (NSInteger)nr_composedCharacterSequenceCount
{
    __block NSInteger count = 0;
    [self enumerateSubstringsInRange:(NSRange){0, self.length}
                             options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences | NSStringEnumerationSubstringNotRequired
                          usingBlock:^(NSString * _Nullable substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                              count += 1;
                          }];
    return count;
}
@end
```

This snippet adds a category to NSString that lets your easily calculate the number of characters:

```
NSLog(@"count: %@", @(@"Roger is a nice guy".composedCharacterSequenceCount));
NSLog(@"count: %@", @(@"रॉजर एक छान माणूस आहे".composedCharacterSequenceCount));
NSLog(@"count: %@", @(@"罗杰是一个好人".composedCharacterSequenceCount));
```

prints:

```
count: 19
count: 16
count: 7
```

Comment: Thanks Nikolai, great help given.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me :

```
NSUInteger stringLength = [string lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding] / 4;
```